# How to remove special characters from the column values using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on cleaning a dataset. I am looking to perform cleaning column values. I want to remove all the special characters except  /_ - .

Input values:

```
column1             column2

ABC/256/36_5         India
AcZ-55/#CZ/567?      USA
AZQR/26"56"/67,55    UK
PQR/665/NZ-89/556^   Russia
AcZ-55/#CZ/567_22    Italy
```

Expected output:

```
column1             column2

ABC/256/36_5         India
AcZ-55/CZ/567        USA
AZQR/2656/6755       UK
PQR/665/NZ-89/556    Russia
AcZ-55/CZ/567_22     Italy
```

I have been using the code:

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W',''))
```

But the above script removes all the special characters from the column whereas i have been looking to remove except /_ - .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the negation operator `^`:

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.replace('([^\w/-])', '')
```

Output:

```
             column1 column2
0       ABC/256/36_5   India
1      AcZ-55/CZ/567     USA
2     AZQR/2656/6755      UK
3  PQR/665/NZ-89/556  Russia
4   AcZ-55/CZ/567_22   Italy
```